# If statement in bat file works wrong

Tags: batch-file

I don't have any experience with writing shell commands or bat files. I come up with a little script with the help of chatGPT. But there is a problem! I want this script to check the given folder size and delete its contents if it is over than 10 MB. But even though the size of the folder is not over than 10 MB it deletes the contents of the folder. I checked the folder path and size and everything seems right. But I couldn't figure out why. What am I missing?

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "folderPath=C:\xx"

REM Get the folder size in bytes
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%a in (`dir "%folderPath%" /s ^| findstr "File(s)"`) do (
    set "folderSize=%%a"
)

REM Check if folder size exceeds 10MB
if %folderSize% gtr 10000000 (
    echo Folder size: {%folderSize%} exceeds 10MB. Deleting contents...
    del /s /q "%folderPath%\*"
    echo Contents deleted.
) else (
    echo Folder size: {%folderSize%} is within the limit.
)

endlocal
```

[image]

Comment: Don't mind the folderPath in the pasted code. I purposely pasted it like that. The actual code is like in the image above.

Comment: Your entire question makes no sense. If you have a parent directory containing child directories, and those theselves have substructures, then all of those substructures are also content of the child directories, and need not be checked at all. A directory does not have a size, what you are talking about is the total size of all of the files within it and its substructure. For that reason, you should only need to determine the total size of each of those children. In order to help answer your question, we need you to better explain exactly what your intention is, by showing a before and after.

Comment: BTW, if you upen a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should note that you can override the default reporting of sizes with thousand separators, by including the `/-C` option. Doing that will give it an output more like `10000000` than the `10.000.000` style you have now.

Comment: I want to clear my temp directory periodically but instead of doing this by hand, I want to make it with the script. I will run this script once a week (from the task scheduler) and it must check the size of the temp directory with all the things inside it doesn't matter if it is content or subdirectory and if the size of the temp directory exceeds 10 GB it must delete all the things inside the temp directory. So basically this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `7.244.399` is not a number. You need to remove the dots to get a number (Compo already showed the easiest way). Note: it will still fail (i.e. show unexpected behaviour sometimes), if the size is above ~2GB.

Comment: Btw: `dir /s` shows you the size of each subfolder separately - you have to add them up to get the total size. Your code will only show the size of the last found subfolder.

Comment: The task seems crazy too, if you're scheduling this task weekly, why not just empty the directory reqardless of its size. Also, Windows already has a program to safely deal with temporary files, the Disk CleanUp tool. Learn how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/automating-disk-cleanup-tool).

Comment: I will check out the tool thanks for your help and time.